# why I couldn't escape single quote in sed replacement but using \x27 worked?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

I'm trying to replace something with 4 single quotes but escaping doesn't work for some reason I don't know!

here is my not working command:

```
sed -r 's/\*\*(.*)\*\*/\'\'\1\'\'/' file
```

I don't know why it output error even tho I escaped the quotes.

I know I could solve the issue using double quotes like:

```
sed -r "s/\*\*(.*)\*\*/\'\'\1\'\'/"
```

or:

```
sed -r 's/\*\*(.*)\*\*/\x27\x27\1\x27\x27/'
```

but yes I just want to know the reason why the first form doesn't work. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, using `\x27` is imo the correct and most readable approach.

About your question, the problem is related to bash's single quoted strings. You cannot escape a single quote inside a single quoted string. From the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html#Single-Quotes):

> **3.1.2.2 Single Quotes**
>
> Enclosing characters in single quotes (‘'’) preserves the literal value of each character within the quotes. A single quote may not occur between single quotes, even when preceded by a backslash.

Meaning this does *not* work:

```
echo 'ab\'c'
```

You need to end the quoted string, add an escaped quote and start the single quoted string again:

```
echo 'ab'\''c'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because between single quotes backslash `\` is literal and have no other meaning including escaping. ANSI-C quoting can be used instead : $'string'

[Reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)